# More rows after Left Join in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join

I've two tables, table1 contains 22780 rows. Now I left join table1 with table2 (which doesn't contain any duplicates) and I get 23588 rows.

```
SELECT   * FROM Table1
left join Tabelle6 ON CAST(Table1.Customer AS Int) = table2.Customer
```

Why do I get more rows now? I only need every row from table1 once.

Edit: found my issue, table 2 does contain duplicates. But is there any way to join every row only once and ignore any further matches?

Comment: Is  `DISTINCT` enought once you narrowed your `SELECT *` to select only the needed field ?

Comment: Thanks for that hint! If I understand this correctly, this only works if table2 contains complete duplicate rows right?

Comment: With this amount of information I can only show a way and you will have to do everything else. Take the second exemple of Tim and replace Table With `SELECT MIN(id) AS id, NeededField FROM Table2 GROUP BY NeededField `

Comment: Can you provide more information to make this question close to answerable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comment suggests, the easiest way to handle this would probably be to do `SELECT DISTINCT` to remove duplicates from your result set:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    t1.col1,
    t1.col2,
    t1.Customer,
    ...
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
    ON CAST(t1.Customer AS Int) = t2.Customer
```

But there is another option here.  We could also join to a subquery which removes duplicate customers.  This would ensure that no record from the first table gets duplicated from matching to more than one record in the second table.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT Customer
    FROM Table2
) t2
    ON CAST(t1.Customer AS Int) = t2.Customer
```

Comment: That looks excellent. Thank you!. However if table2 contains rows, which have duplicates on the join attribute but are otherwise different, then I still get multiple rows. Is there any way to select only the first result from table2 for every join-attibute?

Comment: The `first result` is not a well-defined thing.  How are you defining "first" in this context?  You could aggregate on the columns on the second table and use `GROUP BY`, but we would need to see some concrete data to give an answer.

Comment: "Well-defined thing" With such background information, `42` will be a valid answer. Select on Min(id) or Max(id) based on what First mean.